# How to mention the team-tag when sending message in channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Currently, I have a chat-bot app that sends the message on the channel.

Also, it is capable of tagging a user. The below code is responsible for sending user mentioned message.

```
await turnContext.sendActivity(
 {
    text: `Hello <at>@${members[0].dispName}</at>`,
    entities: [
                {
                            type: 'mention',
                            mentioned: {
                                id: members[0].userName,
                                name: members[0].dispName,
                            },
                            text: `<at>@${members[0].dispName}</at>`,
                }
    ],
});
```

Further, I am trying to mention the **Team Tag**. Is there a way I can pass the **team-id** or something else to mention the **Tag**

**Note:** Team tag means - tag in a team

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer this doc(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagemention?view=graph-rest-1.0) and check if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Now you can create/Get teams tags using Beta Graph API.
Reference doc: [Create teamworkTag - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

You can also get the created tags using below Beta Graph API:
GET /teams/{team-Id}/tags
[List teamworkTags - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

You can also send the message with mentioning teams tag using below API
Post request: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam) id}/channels/{channel id}/messages

Message body:

```
{
  "subject": "This is very urgent!",
  "importance": "urgent",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "Programmatically mentioning of Tagged users <at id=\"0\">String_1234</at>"
  },
  "mentions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "mentionText": "String_1234",
      "mentioned": {
        "tag": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.teamworkTagIdentity",
          "id": ""/*tag id*/,
          "displayName": ""/* tag name*/
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```